# Reading empty string from consul using spring-cloud-consul

Tags: java, spring, consul, spring-cloud-consul, consul-kv

I'm migrating from file based .properties file to consul based configuration in my spring application. I'm using spring-cloud-consul. Earlier in my property file I had a property like following

`test.key=`

In spring application class corresponding field is like this

`@Value("${test.key:defaultVal}")
private String testConsul;`

In the runtime, the value of `testConsul` string is an empty string. But when using the consul, whenever I put key `test.key` without a value, in the runtime it gets resolved to a `null`.

Is there anyway I can pass an empty string value through consul ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the work around we're using. use a default value which is not exist

`${no.such.key:}`

Hope this helps.